# Svg error Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg, next.js

I am implementing a navigation bar component via svg image with Next.js.

I tried to import and use the svg image, but an error was found and could not be resolved.

I used emotion js and created and used svg, but found the following error.
[image]

how can i solve it??

```js
//navBar.tsx
const Add: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({ width, height }) => (
  <svg width={width} height={height} viewBox="0 0 40 38" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="10" cy="19.5" r="9.5" transform="rotate(-90 10 19.5)" fill="#F292B7" />
    <circle cx="20" cy="28.5" r="9.5" fill="#0066D9" />
    <circle cx="30" cy="19.5" r="9.5" transform="rotate(-90 30 19.5)" fill="#00AC62" />
    <circle cx="20" cy="9.5" r="9.5" fill="#0066D9" />
    <path
      fillRule="evenodd"
      clipRule="evenodd"
      d="M19.4863 18.9864C14.6486 18.7286 10.7714 14.8515 10.5136 10.0137C15.3514 10.2714 19.2286 14.1486 19.4863 18.9864Z"
      fill="#F292B7"
    />
    <rect x="19" y="11" width="3" height="16" rx="1.5" fill="white" />
    <rect x="12.5" y="20.5" width="3" height="16" rx="1.5" transform="rotate(-90 12.5 20.5)" fill="white" />
  </svg>


const NavBar = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <NavBarContainer>
      <li>
        <Link href="/">
          <a>
            <Home width="24 " height="27" stroke={router.asPath === "/" ? Common.colors.BL500 : Common.colors.GY900} />
            <Span>홈</Span>
          </a>
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link href="/survey">
          <a>
            <Survey width="30" height="27" stroke={router.asPath === "/survey" ? Common.colors.BL500 : Common.colors.GY900} />
            <Span>서베이</Span>
          </a>
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link href="/add">
          <Add width={40} height={40} />  //error
        </Link>
      </li>
    </NavBarContainer>
  );
};
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to wrap `<Add/>` with an empty `<a>` tag.

```
<Link href="/add">
  <a>
    <Add width={40} height={40} />
  </a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround!
Could you please explain why this is happening??

Comment: @김정수 If the child of `Link` is a functional component you need to wrap it with `React.forwardRef`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-functional-component. Wrapping your component with `<a>` instead works around this as the `<a>` itself becomes the direct child of `Link`.